# apache2 vhost loads wrong project

Tags: php, apache, dns, apache2, vhosts

TL;DR:
I have two VHOST's but the second one (phpmyadmin.conf) does point to the directory of the first one.

---

I have four VHOST's:

- phpmyadmin.conf
- phpmyadmin_ssl.conf
- test_api_konfigurator.conf
- test_api_konfigurator_ssl.conf

---

#### /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 test.api.konfigurator.company.de
127.0.0.1 phpmyadmin.aws1.company.de

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

---

The two subdomains are just CNAME records from my **DNS server** to my project server:

```
phpmyadmin.aws1.company.de.         300 CNAME   ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com
test.api.konfigurator.company.de.   300 CNAME   ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

---

## Problem:

Both project's have a "index.php" with this code `exit("hello from phpmyadmin.aws1.company.de");` and respectively `exit("hello from test.api.konfigurator.company.de");` in the first line.

If I call `https://test.api.konfigurator.company.de` or `http://test.api.konfigurator.company.de`
then I get to see "*hello from test.api.konfigurator.company.de*" as expected.

But if I call `https://phpmyadmin.aws1.company.de` or `http://phpmyadmin.aws1.company.de` then I also get "*hello from test.api.konfigurator.company.de*"

### VHOST Config files

**1. phpmyadmin.conf**

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName phpmyadmin.aws1.company.de
        ServerAdmin black@company.de
        DocumentRoot /usr/share/phpmyadmin

        <Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/phpmyadmin_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/phpmyadmin_access.log combined

        # Redirect from http to https
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
    </VirtualHost>

    # vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

**2. phpmyadmin_ssl.conf**

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName phpmyadmin.aws1.company.de
        ServerAdmin black@company.de
        DocumentRoot /usr/share/phpmyadmin

        <Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/phpmyadmin_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/phpmyadmin_access.log combined

        # Example SSL configuration
        SSLEngine on
        SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
        SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5
        SSLCertificateFile "/etc/ssl/certs/company/hoster_cert"
        SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/ssl/certs/company/hoster_key"
    </VirtualHost>

    # vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

3. test_api_konfigurator.conf

   ```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName test.api.konfigurator.company.de
        ServerAdmin black@company.de
        DocumentRoot /var/www/company/test.api.konfigurator.company.de/public

        <Directory /var/www/company/test.api.konfigurator.company.de/public>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/test_api_konfigurator_company_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/test_api_konfigurator_company_access.log combined

        # Redirect from http to https
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
    </VirtualHost>

    # vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
   ```
4. test_api_konfigurator_ssl.conf

   ```
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName test.api.konfigurator.company.de
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/company/test.api.konfigurator.company.de/public

        <Directory /var/www/company/test.api.konfigurator.company.de/public>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/test_api_konfigurator_company_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/test_api_konfigurator_company_access.log combined

        # Example SSL configuration
        SSLEngine on
        SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
        SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5
        SSLCertificateFile "/etc/ssl/certs/company/hoster_cert"
        SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/ssl/certs/company/hoster_key"
    </VirtualHost>

    # vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
   ```

### Details:

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and Apache 2.4.52

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. My **phpmyadmin_ssl.conf** VHOST has Port 80 while it needs 443.

#### phpmyadmin_ssl.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName phpmyadmin.aws1.company.de
    ServerAdmin black@company.de
    DocumentRoot /usr/share/phpmyadmin

    <Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/phpmyadmin_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/phpmyadmin_access.log combined

    # Example SSL configuration
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
    SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5
    SSLCertificateFile "/etc/ssl/certs/company/hoster_cert"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/ssl/certs/company/hoster_key"
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```